# Unable to View Files in Folder

Tags: linux, ntfs

Recently got a new external drive named "ShowDrive" below. However I'm unable to view any of the contents within the "TV" Folder. When I try to `ls` the folder i'm just presented with `Input/output error`.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /media/pi/ShowDrive/
total 1232
drwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi      0 Nov 18 18:15 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 549227 Apr 22  2022 'Install Western Digital Software for Mac.dmg'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 671824 Jul  9  2021 'Install Western Digital Software for Windows.exe'
drwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi      0 Nov 19 09:12 'System Volume Information'
drwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi  24576 Nov 21 14:06  TV
```

Other folders such as the `System Volume Information` seem to open just fine, and there seems to be no issues when opening on a Windows computer.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL      UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                               
├─sda1                                                                            
└─sda2      ntfs   MovieDrive 3C8412A6841262A6                        3.2T    78% /media/pi/MovieDrive
sdb                                                                               
└─sdb1      ntfs   ShowDrive  1EC4AADFC4AAB903                        8.8T    52% /media/pi/ShowDrive
mmcblk0                                                                           
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   boot       9F2D-0578                             203.9M    19% /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4   rootfs     efc2ea8b-042f-47f5-953e-577d8860de55   32.8G    40% /
```

`dmesg` output is below:

```
[  121.932399] v3d fec00000.v3d: MMU error from client L2T (0) at 0x3ea1000, pte invalid
[  231.567759] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  231.599180] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25a3, bcdDevice=10.31
[  231.599203] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  231.599223] usb 2-1: Product: Elements 25A3
[  231.599240] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[  231.599258] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 324C474153394B4B
[  231.603736] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  231.614083] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[  232.678425] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 25A3    1031 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  232.679549] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  232.683288] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  233.717328] ...................ready
[  252.438006] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  252.438268] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 39063584768 512-byte logical blocks: (20.0 TB/18.2 TiB)
[  252.438285] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  252.439044] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  252.439063] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[  252.439857] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  252.439874] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  252.535654] Alternate GPT is invalid, using primary GPT.
[  252.535689]  sdb: sdb1
[  252.538565] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

How do I go about making the folder readable?

Logs in `/var/log/messages`

```
Dec  2 09:30:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  231.567759] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Dec  2 09:30:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  231.599180] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25a3, bcdDevice=10.31
Dec  2 09:30:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  231.599203] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec  2 09:30:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  231.599223] usb 2-1: Product: Elements 25A3
Dec  2 09:30:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  231.599240] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
Dec  2 09:30:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  231.599258] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 324C474153394B4B
Dec  2 09:30:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  231.603736] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec  2 09:30:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  231.614083] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
Dec  2 09:30:41 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 3: "/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-1"
Dec  2 09:30:41 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Dec  2 09:30:41 raspberrypi kernel: [  232.678425] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 25A3    1031 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Dec  2 09:30:41 raspberrypi kernel: [  232.679549] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Dec  2 09:30:41 raspberrypi kernel: [  232.683288] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
Dec  2 09:30:41 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 3: "/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-1"
Dec  2 09:30:41 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Dec  2 09:31:01 raspberrypi kernel: [  233.717328] ...................ready
Dec  2 09:31:01 raspberrypi kernel: [  252.438006] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
Dec  2 09:31:01 raspberrypi kernel: [  252.438268] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 39063584768 512-byte logical blocks: (20.0 TB/18.2 TiB)
Dec  2 09:31:01 raspberrypi kernel: [  252.438285] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
Dec  2 09:31:01 raspberrypi kernel: [  252.439044] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Dec  2 09:31:01 raspberrypi kernel: [  252.535654] Alternate GPT is invalid, using primary GPT.
Dec  2 09:31:01 raspberrypi kernel: [  252.535689]  sdb: sdb1
Dec  2 09:31:01 raspberrypi kernel: [  252.538565] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Dec  2 09:31:04 raspberrypi udisksd[431]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /media/pi/ShowDrive on behalf of uid 1000
```

Comment: I assume that you installed `ntfs-3g`.  `Input/output error`, in general, means that there is something wrong with the hardware of the drive. The message `Alternate GPT is invalid, using primary GPT.` is also not very encouraging. In general, you should have some error messages in `/var/log/messages` as well.

Comment: `ntfs-3g` is installed and on the newest version (1:2017.3.23AR.3-3+deb10u3). Added the messages in `/var/log/messages`

Comment: Is that all in `/var/log/messages`? Or did you not do an `ls` that caused the IO-error. I would have expected the IO error to leave some traces in `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: Seems to be all the messages in `/var/log/messages`. The IO-error appears when running `ls` only on a specific folder.

Comment: If you can open it in Windows, have you tried checking it for errors there?

Comment: As I said, IO errors are, in general an indication of hardware issues. If it is just a specific set of files/directories, it is in general bad blocks. Unmount the drive and use `badblocks -n -vv /dev/sdb` to find out.